# Why won't my Rails model save into the Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

```
  def self.build_prior_month(payee, as_of = Time.current, opts = {})    
    start_date, end_date, year, month = effective_dates(as_of)

    statement = payee.earnings_statements.build(
      :year => year,
      :month => month,
      :balance => 0,
      :revenue => 0
    )

    statement.generate(start_date, end_date, year, month)
    statement.update_totals

    statement
  end
```

That's a function that I have in a model of mine. It returns `statement` properly, but doesn't save to the database. Why is that?

The `generate` function looks like:

```
  def generate_ledger_items(start_date, end_date, year, month)
    payee.ledger_entries.for_month_and_year(month, year).each do |entry|
      earnings_statement_items.build(
        :items => entry.item_group,
        :units => entry.units,
        :net_revenue => entry.net_revenue,
        :net_revenue_per_unit => [entry.net_revenue, entry.units].all? ? (entry.net_revenue / entry.units).round(2) : nil,
        :fees => entry.service_fees,
        :payments_collected => entry.spendings,
        :fee_terms => entry.terms || entry.description, # When would terms be set?
        :due => entry.credit || -entry.debit
      )
    end
  end

  def update_totals
    self.revenue  = earnings_statement_items.net_revenue
    self.balance = earnings_statement_items.total
  end
```

Comment: Because you never save it in the database. Unless you do it in update_totals? `build` just creates the object, it doesn't save it to the database. What is the source for update_totals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `build` method on your association does not actually save the record into the database. `create` will. It is similar to the difference between `new` and `create` on your models.

```
statement = payee.earnings_statements.create(
  :year => year,
  :month => month,
  :balance => 0,
  :revenue => 0
)
```

Will save your record. See the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).

Comment: Can I use `statement.save!`?

Answer (score 1):

.build doesn't save the object

call:

```
statement.save
```